# Validation of simple code

Tags: html, validation

I am staring at this code for 20 minutes, but I just don´t know, where the mistake is. I need to revalidate it. Can you help me? Validator says: document type does not allow element "DIV" here; missing one of "APPLET", "OBJECT", "MAP", "IFRAME", "BUTTON" start-tag

```
<div class="adress">
     <span class="fn org"><strong>Text</strong></span><br>
     <span class="adr">
          <span class="street-address">Some text</span><br>
          <span class="postal-code">Some text<span class="locality">Text</span>Text</span>
     </span><br>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you trying to validate just this snippet of HTML code? Or is there more that you aren't sharing with us?

Comment: There is more code, but it has the same error when you validate only this piece of code.

Comment: Well, using the official W3C HTML validator, I don't get any div errors like you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

The error is not in the code posted but in the code around it. As the validator’s explanation for the error message says (explanations in brackets mine):

> The mentioned element [the `div` element] is not allowed to appear in the context in which
>   you've placed it; the other mentioned elements are the only ones that
>   are both allowed there and can contain the element mentioned. This
>   might mean that you need a containing element, or possibly that you've
>   forgotten to close a previous element.
>
> One possible cause for this message is that you have attempted to put
>   a block-level element (such as "`<p>`" or "`<table>`" [or "`<div>`]") inside an inline
>   element (such as "`<a>`", "`<span>`", or "`<font>`").

For example, if the `div` element is inside a link, `<a href="..."><div ...></div></a>`, the nesting is invalid according to HTML 4.01 rules, which you are validating against (though valid according to HTML5 CR).